# im getting error when im trying to import file on firebase storage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

i have been trying to import files from firebase storage but im getting errors i have read the documentation and also read some blogs on it but still the same error. i'm just looking for the best way to go about this

```
import { storage } from '../Firebase/firebase';
import { getStorage, ref, getDownloadURL, uploadBytesResumable } from "firebase/storage";

async function storeImage(image){
            return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
                const storage = getStorage()
                const filename = `${auth.currentUser.uid}-${image.name}-${uuidv4()}`
                const storageRef = ref(storage, filename)
                const uploadTask = uploadBytesResumable(storageRef, file);
                uploadTask.on('state_changed', 
                    (snapshot) => {
            // Observe state change events such as progress, pause, and resume
            // Get task progress, including the number of bytes uploaded and the total number of bytes to be uploaded
            const progress = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
            console.log('Upload is ' + progress + '% done');
            switch (snapshot.state) {
            case 'paused':
                console.log('Upload is paused');
                break;
            case 'running':
                console.log('Upload is running');
                break;
            }
        }, 
        (error) => {
            // Handle unsuccessful uploads
            reject(error)
        }, 
        () => {
            // Handle successful uploads on complete
            // For instance, get the download URL: https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/...
            getDownloadURL(uploadTask.snapshot.ref).then((downloadURL) => {
              resolve(downloadURL);
            });
        }
        );
                    })

            }

        
        const ImgUrl = await Promise.all(
            [...images].map((image)=>storeImage(image)).catch((error)=>{
                setLoading(false);
                toast.error("images cannot be uploaded")
                return;
            })
        )
        console.log(ImgUrl)
        
        

         
    }
```

this is the my config file have been ive imported but isn't working

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getStorage } from "firebase/storage";

const firebaseConfig = {
   piKey: "AIzaSyBBP9H3mLn7Nz8NeCo4Rve87YszflMshZ8",
  authDomain: "realtor-e7363.firebaseapp.com",
  projectId: "realtor-e7363",
  storageBucket: "realtor-e7363.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "960865969593",
  appId: "1:960865969593:web:9fde225122d9555ec00268",
};

// Use this to initialize the firebase App
// Use these for db & auth
const db = firebaseApp.firestore();
const auth = firebase.auth();
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export const storage = getStorage(app);
export { auth, db };
```

ive tried importing the files and read some documentation on it but isn't working through

Comment: "im getting errors" Please edit your question to include the exact error message and complete stack trace that you get.

Answer (score 0):

Your Firebase config file needs to be adapted as follows (See also the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#access-firebase)):

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getStorage } from "firebase/storage";
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";

const firebaseConfig = {
  //...
};


const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const auth = getAuth(app);
const db = getFirestore(app);
const storage = getStorage(app);

export { auth, db, storage };
```

---

In addition you don't need to use again `getStorage` as follows

```
import { storage } from '../Firebase/firebase';
import { getStorage, ref, getDownloadURL, uploadBytesResumable } from "firebase/storage";

async function storeImage(image){
            return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
                const storage = getStorage()
                //...
                const storageRef = ref(storage, filename)
                //...
```

Just do:

```
import { storage } from '../Firebase/firebase';
import { ref, getDownloadURL, uploadBytesResumable } from "firebase/storage";

async function storeImage(image){
            return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
                const storageRef = ref(storage, filename)
                //...
```

Comment: import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { getFirestore, collection, getDocs } from 'firebase/firestore/lite';
import { getStorage } from '@firebase/storage';
// Follow this pattern to import other Firebase services
// import { } from 'firebase/<service>';

// TODO: Replace the following with your app's Firebase project configuration
const firebaseConfig = {
 //////
  
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export const db = getFirestore(app);
export const storage = getStorage(app);

Comment: @AderobaDayoJerry What is the aim of your comment?

Comment: i want to be able to uploaded images/file to my firebase storage and also retrieve images/files